# Change success message in plugin Theme my login

Tags: plugins, login

I am using theme my login plugin and want to replace message when people registered and it's redirect back to login page with displaying message at the top of the form.

**Message:**
`Your registration was successful but you must now confirm your email address before you can log in. Please check your email and click on the link provided.`

I want to replace this message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below should work as is (with your strings for the new message and the theme's text domain), when inserted in your theme's *functions.php*:

```
function wpse71032_change_tml_registration_message( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( $domain === 'theme-my-login' &&
        $text === 'Your registration was successful but you must now confirm your email address before you can log in. Please check your email and click on the link provided.'
    ) {
        /* in the below, change the first argument to the message you want
           and the second argument to your theme's textdomain */
        $translated_text = __( '%Registration Message%', 'theme_text_domain' );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse71032_change_tml_registration_message', 20, 3 );
```

See [the article on the gettext filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) in the Filter Reference.

Comment: It is not changing the message. here what I have replaced if I am wrong somewhere `$translated_text = __( 'Check your email Inbox or Junk/Spam folder for verification link', 'marinebox' ); //marinebox is my theme name`

Comment: That was my mistake.. it's working now. Thanks a lot!